# Rails Strong_params passing "param is missing"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, balanced-payments

I have a rails 4.1 app that is using Balanced to process credit cards. The credit card form I have is using ajax to post to the backend but I am getting the following error:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing - param is missing or the value is empty
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:183:in `require'
```

here is my controller:

```
class TablechargesController < ApplicationController
def new
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @table = @event.tablecharges.build
end

def index
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @table = @event.tablecharges.all
end

def create
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @table = @event.tablecharges.build(table_charge_params)
    if @table.save
        redirect_to @event, :notice => "Thanks for the cash"
    else
        render :new
    end
end

private


def table_charge_params
    params.require(:tablecharge).permit(:uri, event_attributes: :id)
end

end
```

here is my model:

```
class Tablecharge < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :event
attr_accessor :cc_name
attr_accessor :cc_number
attr_accessor :cc_expiration_month
attr_accessor :cc_expiration_year
attr_accessor :cc_ccv
attr_accessor :uri
end
```

here is my Javascript:

```
jQuery ->
$('#cc-submit').click (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()

    handleResponse = (response) ->
        if (response.status_code == 201)

            fundingInstrument = (if response.cards? then response.cards[0] else response.bank_accounts[0])

            alert(fundingInstrument.href)

            $('#tablecharge_uri').val(fundingInstrument.href)

            url = '/events/' + urlid + '/tablecharges'

            alert(url)

            jQuery.ajax({type: "POST", url: url, data: {uri: fundingInstrument.href, event_id: urlid}, sucess: (data) ->
                alert data.id
            error: (data) ->
                alert "fuck"})

        else
            alert(response.status + JSON.stringify(response, false, 1))

    payload = {
    name: $('#cc-name').val()
    number: $('#cc-number').val()
    expiration_month: $('#cc-expiration-month').val()
    expiration_year: $('#cc-expiration-year').val()
    ccv: $('#cc-ccv').val()
    }

    balanced.card.create(payload, handleResponse)
```

here is my view:

```
<div class="authform">
<%= javascript_tag do %>
window.urlid = "<%= @table.event_id %>"
<% end %>
<%= simple_form_for [@event, @table] do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :cc_name, input_html: {id: 'cc-name'}%>
    <%= f.input :cc_number, input_html: {id: 'cc-number'} %>
    <%= f.input :cc_expiration_month, as: :integer, input_html: {id: 'cc-expiration-month'} %>
    <%= f.input :cc_expiration_year, as: :integer, input_html: {id: 'cc-expiration-year'} %>
    <%= f.input :cc_ccv, input_html: {id: 'cc-ccv'} %>
    <%= f.input :uri, as: :hidden %>
    <%= f.button :submit, id: 'cc-submit', remote: true  %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

The first value in your `data` object has to be `:tablecharge` as you specified that all the `params` belong to *that* object.

So the `data` you are passing in your `ajax request` should be formatted like this:

```
data: { tablecharge: {uri: fundingInstrument.href, event_id: urlid}}
```

Comment: When you pass `params` through a normal `Ruby form` you are passing it in the same nested way so you need to mimic the data that `Rails` is expecting in your `Javascript`.

Comment: I reformatted the data object and now im not getting the post to run? im also not getting anything from the console?

Comment: it gives me the alerts before the ajax post and then it just ends with nothing coming up on the rails console or the chrome debugger?

Comment: @adminbanks can you update your question to reflect what you changed and i can take a loook

Comment: Spent literally all night trying to find the out why my data wasnt posting only to realize I wasn't actually wrapping the object in the model name like the author mentions above.  Wow, always the little things